# Как сделать проверку на пароль

Tags: python, mysql

Мне нужно сделать так ,чтобы при написании существующего логина и ПРАВИЛЬНОГО пароля, входилось в логин. Логин проверяется, а пароль нет

Возьму несколько строк и покажу их:

```
global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cu = db.cursor()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    win INT,
    cash INT
)""")
db.commit()

user_login = input('Ваше имя:')
password_login = input('Ваш пароль:')
cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'") #проверка логина
if cu.fetchone() is None:
    cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0, 0))
    db.commit()
    print("Зарегистрировано")
else:
    print(f"Добро пожаловать, {user_login}!")
```

Comment: Ну вы делайте `SELECT` не логина, а пароля. Получайте его через `cu.fetchone()` и сравнивайте с введённым. Хотя обычно пароли в явном виде не хранят, хранят хеш пароля и сравнивают его с хэшем введённого пароля.

Comment: @CrazyElf как можно сделать это через ```cu.fetchone()```?